# How does one correctly override AsyncTask onPostExecute() method?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using `AsyncTask` to make an API call. My `AsyncTask` is supposed to send two images to a facial recognition service and return a `Double` contained in the JSON response from the service.

However, I keep getting this error regarding `onPostExecute()`:

```
Error:(44, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from >a supertype
```

I don't understand why I get this error.

Here is my `AsyncTask` subclass:

```
public class KairosManager extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, JSONObject> {

    // MainActivity Context
    private Context mContext;

    public KairosManager(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }


    // Call Kairos API and return JSONObject response to doInBackground()

    public JSONObject compareImages(Bitmap bm1, Bitmap bm2){
        // Kairos Call here!
        return jsonResponse;
    }


    // Take both images in the array and call compareImages which calls the service.

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Bitmap... params){
        Bitmap bm1 = params[0];
        Bitmap bm2 = params[1];
        return compareImages(bm1, bm2);
    }


    // Parse JSONObject response and return 'confidence' value to MainActivity

    @Override
    protected Double onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
        try{
            JSONArray TwoImages = result.getJSONArray(IMAGES);
            JSONObject image = TwoImages.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject subimage = image.getJSONObject(TRANSACTION);
            Double confidence = subimage.getDouble(CONFIDENCE);
            Log.d("Percent: ", confidence.toString());
            return confidence;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
    Bitmap bm1 = ((BitmapDrawable) image1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bm2 = ((BitmapDrawable) image2.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    KairosManager myKairosManager = new KairosManager(this);
    myKairosManager.execute(bm1, bm2);
```

Comment: Three dots `...` means that zero or more objects (or an array of them) may be passed as the parameter(s) for that function.

Comment: it is called varargs. you can use it as an array of objects. In your case is an array of ArrayList<Bitmap>

Comment: You should read this again http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `doInBackground` method should return an object of type `Double`.

Comment: Right now doInBackground returns the JSON response and onPostExecute parses it and returns the value of interest.

Are you suggesting that doInBackground should parse the JSONObject and return the value of interest too? Then my onPostExecute would be redundant.

Comment: @Jacobo Replace `<ArrayList<Bitmap>, Void, Double>` with `<ArrayList<Bitmap>, Void, JSONObject>`, the error will go away.

Comment: I have made the changes you mentioned. Now I just have to figure out how to send the Double back to the MainActivity, but that is a different matter. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use Java interfaces & callbacks.

Comment: All I need is to TextView.setText(confidence.toString());
Can I do that directly from the AsyncTask class, or do I need to use Interfaces and Callbacks to send the confidence back to MainActivity and setText there?

Comment: @Jacobo If your `AsyncTask` class is an _inner class_ of your `Activity`, directly is possible. Otherwise, Java interface is required.